# How to touch a HABTM relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

If you have 2 models, Video and Category and they have a "has_and_belongs_to_many" relation with each other, how do you perform a touch to invalidate the cache when one of them changes?

You can't put "touch" on them like you can with a one-to-many relation. Now when i change a category name, the videos that belong to that category don't know about the change until i invalidate the cache. My View Templates show the name of the Category for each Video.

Comment: I don't think it exists for HABTM as it would likely not perform very well. Is there any reason you cannot use a callback to do the same thing?

Comment: No i'd use anything to get this working. Can you give me a direction on how to touch with a callback?

Comment: Drop HABTM and use `has_many :through`.

Comment: Do you have category name cached in video model? Could you write this in question to make it more explicit?

Comment: Yes they have, i have added it to the question, thanks.

Comment: As @meagar noticed you can use ```has_many :through``` and use touch option on ```belongs_to``` in CategoryVideo.

Comment: Wouldn't i have to create another model for that? I am curious about what @d_ethier said, on using a callback. Can anyone comment on that? thanks all

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On the model that you want to update you can do something like this:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories,
                          after_add: :touch_updated_at,
                          after_remove: :touch_updated_at

  def touch_updated_at(category)
    self.touch if persisted?
  end

end
```

Now, whenever a category is added to or removed from a video, the video's updated_at timestamp will get updated. You can do the same thing on the category class if you want categories to update when videos are added to or removed from them.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks ! I wanted to changed the video when categories are added or removed, not when categories themselves are updated.

Answer (score 14):

Touch can be used only in two case.

**On a record**

```
category = Category.first
category.touch
```

**On a belongs_to relation**

```
belongs_to :category, :touch => true
```

So if you want to use it on a HABTM relation, I'm afraid that you'll have to do it manually. It could be something like:

```
class Category
  before_save :touch_videos

  def touch_videos
    videos.touch
  end
end

class Video
  def self.touch
    update_attributes(:updated_at => Time.now)
    # or
    each { |video| video.touch } # Make a proper touch
  end
end
```

Be aware that if you want to allow Video to touch categories as well, you'll have to find a way to avoid "circular" updates.

**each & find_each**

If you prefer each over update_attributes, use find_each to load records by batch. This will avoid loading all records at the same time in memory and potentially crash the application. If you don't have 10k records, you probably won't see any difference, but as your table grows, it will get slower or even break if you use each.

```
find_each(batch_size: 2000) { |video| video.touch }
```

Comment: That helps a lot thanks. Luckily at the moment i don't need videos to touch categories :)

Comment: `touch_videos` should probably be `videos.each(&:touch)`

Comment: I would also avoid `each` in the Video class. Instead.. `update_all(updated_at: Time.now)` which would only be a single SQL query, `each` will be n+1

Comment: Thanks basgys and Lee. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Note: `touch` and `update_all` do not trigger validations or callbacks, except in the case of `touch` as it will trigger an `after touch` callback but no other callbacks. If there is a `touch` executed on a relationship that also touches your original model, you will be caught in a circular update infinite loop. IOW, `touch` will trigger a cascading `touch` if specified in any relationship with `touch: true` on the touched object. In the example above using `update_attributes` will cause circular updates if you attempt the same from Video -> Category. Using `update_all` will not cascade.

Comment: `before_save -> { self.videos.each &:touch }, if: :persisted?` is alot cleaner