# Using ROR touch attribute with belongs_to is not working when it's being used in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, touch, many-to-many, associations

I am trying to create a ROR API to allow users to update specific product (contains headline and categories attributes), this product has many-to-many association with category object as following:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    validates :headline, presence: true
    has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, through: :product_categories

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :products, through: :product_categories
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_categories

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
```

I want to change the updated_at field in the Product model whenever any change happened to it's attribute or even to any of it's association (I have used touch attribute in the belong_to in the ProductCategory association) but 
whenever I tried to update the category attribute in the product object, the categories is being updated in the ProductCategory model but the updated_at field in the Product model is not being changed to the current time and the after_touch callback method is not being called.

To fix this I have added self.touch in the after_save method:

```
after_save do
    self.touch if !self.changed? && self.categories_changed?
end
```

Does touch attribute work in the join table (when it's a many-to-many) relation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use touch option in the many to many relationships, as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826140/how-to-touch-a-habtm-relation). As you did, you need to update manually.

BTW, if ProductCategory is nothing but associating two tables, I guess you can use 'has_and_belongs_to_many' relation in the two tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually this is just a snippet of my code. ProductCategory model has other code.

Comment: I see you're using has_many through. And if your question resolved, could you accept my answer?